# Create a hyperlink within an Excel cell?

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to create a hyperlink within an Excel cell which only uses a section of the cell text for the clickable link?  I.E. would the below table mockup represent something that can be easily built in Excel 2010?

[a mock up http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14119404/misc/Microsoft%20Excel%20-%20Book1_2012-04-16_14-24-47.jpg](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14119404/misc/Microsoft%20Excel%20-%20Book1_2012-04-16_14-24-47.jpg)

I know that an entire cell can be made into a hyperlink easily, but not a specific part of the cell as far as I know.

By hyperlink I also refer to either

- (a)another cell or,
- (b)a web URL.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry to report - but link to dropbox returns 404

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible in Excel. Hyperlinks are associated with entire cells.

If you look at the [documentation for the Excel hyperlink object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb242296%28v=office.12%29.aspx), you can see that it's associated with a Range. If it were possible to associate hyperlinks with a span within the cell, the Hyperlink object would need to have an associated Range and [Characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb255882%28v=office.12%29.aspx) object.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Will have to put in a feature request!

Answer (score 17):

After creating the hyperlink you could format the text in the cell so that only the words of interest are underlined/blue.  The hyperlink will still work, but obviously you can still have only one link per cell, and clicking anywhere in the text will trigger the hyperlink.

For example:

[image]

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

    rng.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rng, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        "Sheet1!A10", TextToDisplay:="this is long text"

    With rng.Font
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    End With

    With rng.Characters(Start:=9, Length:=4).Font
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
        .Color = -4165632
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Appreciate the visual work around for single links per cell, though that's quite difficult.  :-)

Answer (score 7):

I needed to link to a filename displayed in a cell, so here is what worked for me:

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(row, column), Address:=file.Path, TextToDisplay:=file.Path
```

Answer (score 1):

The above one liner was very helpful... since I'm new, I couldn't comment.  So here is my variation of the above that takes each row on a worksheet and builds a URL from a value on the row.

```
CHGRow = 3
Worksheets("Page 1").Select
Cells(CHGRow, 1).Select

Do Until Application.CountA(ActiveCell.EntireRow) = 0

    URLVal = "https://our_url_here?some_parameter=" & Cells(CHGRow, cNumber)
    URLText = Cells(CHGRow, cNumber)
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(CHGRow, cURL), Address:=URLVal, TextToDisplay:=URLText

    CHGRow = CHGRow + 1
    Cells(CHGRow, 1).Select

Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a great smoke-and-mirrors solution I've used for creating hyperlinked strings within a larger block of text in an Excel spreadsheet cell.  CAUTION -- if there are multiple editors for your worksheet, this is not advisable as hyperlinks can get misaligned with the text in their cells unless you can provide sufficient protection.  A means of doing that is described in this procedure though may limit what contributors can do:

1. In your Excel spreadsheet, assuming you are not trying to protect ALL cells from editing, select all cells in the worksheet, then select Format Cells from the Home ribbon or the right-click popup menu.  On the Protection tab, check then uncheck the "Locked" checkbox to ensure all cells are unlocked.
2. Now select the (first) cell that will contain the link.
3. Copy (don't cut) the text that you want to appear as a link to the clipboard.
4. Click anywhere in your spreadsheet (an unused area is best) and insert a text box from the Insert ribbon using either the Shape icon dropdown or the Text icon. Size and shape aren't important yet, just approximate the size of the link text.
5. Paste the clipboard contents into the text box.
6. Right click the text box and select Link to add a hyperlink to it, and specify the link target, whether a location in the current document or a URL.
7. Select the link text and format it how you want your links to appear, e.g. blue, underlined, etc., since inside a text box this apparently does not occur automatically as in a cell.
8. Right click the text box again and select Format Shape.  From the Format Shape panel, perform the following in order to properly fit the shape around the text and eliminate white space and border:

       (a) On the Fill & Line panel (1st icon), select the No Line option.

       (b) On the Size & Properties panel (3rd icon), set all 4 margins to zero (0.00"), uncheck the "Wrap text in shape" checkbox, and check the "Resize shape to fit text" textbox."

       (c) Under Properties, ensure the following are selected:

           * Move but don't size with cells

           * Locked

           * Lock text
9. If you need the same hyperlink to occur in multiple cells or locations within the same cell (even if targets differ), clone the text box you did all this work on by selecting its (now invisible) border with a right click (warning - a left click will now take you to the link target instead!), copying it to the clipboard, and press Ctrl+V as many times as you need copies.
10. Right click on the text box (or one of them if you cloned it) and drag it to the cell where you want the link to appear, positioning it directly over the original text that matches your hyperlink, so as to visually cover it up and replace it (the original text serving as a spacer to make room for it).  The steps taken in item 8 above should prevent it from covering up or clipping any text or punctuation surrounding the original text.
11. Select that cell, then from the Format menu on the Home ribbon, select "Lock Cell" to protect its contents from inadvertently changing and misaligning the text box with the corresponding text that its hiding.
12. Repeat steps 10 & 11 for each additional copy of the linked text box you created.  If any of them requires a different link target, simply right click that copy of the text box, select "Edit Link", and update the target.
13. From the Format menu on the Home ribbon, select "Protect Sheet".  Check the box labelled "Protect worksheet and contents of locked cells".
14. Check all the other boxes in that dialog also (assuming you are not trying to restrict users in any of those ways) except for the following:

             * Format cells

             * Format columns

             * Format rows

             * Edit objects

         Leave these four checkboxes unchecked so as to protect your linked text boxes from being selected, deleted, moved, or misaligned with their underlying text. (Note:  They should already move with their underlying cells if rows or columns are added, removed or resized, but without this protection they can still be impacted if their own row or column is resized.)
15. If you want to add a password, do so now.  When finished, click OK to apply protection. You can selected "Unprotect Sheet" from the Format menu later to perform any necessary editing, but if the link cell(s), column(s) or row(s) are edited or resized, you may need to reposition the link text box(es) over the underlying text if it moved.
16. Test your hyperlink(s) and also what happens if you try editing the containing cell(s) or resizing the containing column(s) or row(s) to be sure the worksheet is ready for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

I'd just make your one row into two rows, merge the cells in the columns you need to have it appear to be a single row and when you get to the cell that needs the hyperlink then you put the words on the top cell and the link in the cell below.  It will look fine as a non-techy workaround.