# Excel - Possible to convert text column into hyperlink?

Tags: excel, xlsx

I have over 100 excel files, all with over 1,000 rows of data. One of the columns in a URL, but excel doesn't recognize it as a hyperlink.

I know I can use =HYPERLINK() in a new column to create a link, but is there an easier/more efficient method of converting the URLs in the original column to a clickable link?

Comment: You could do this with some VBA code.  Check out this link for some inspiration / examples.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181995/create-a-hyperlink-within-an-excel-cell

Comment: Or another language like python will allow you to manipulate the data in the sheets.